# phpmyadmin print statement syntax error

Tags: mysql

```
    CREATE TRIGGER agecheck AFTER INSERT ON student
    FOR EACH
    ROW
    BEGIN
    IF (CURRENT_DATE-Dateofbirth) > 16 
    THEN dbms_output.put_line('Age must be greater than 16');
    END IF;
    END;
```

I am trying to write this trigger in phpmyadmin but it gives an error on dbms_output.put_line. It says "you have an error in your sql syntax". Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

`dbms_output.put_line` is an [Oracle pl/sql call](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000105), it is not available in mysql. There is no direct equivalent in mysql's procedural language. The closest thing to this call is perhaps [SIGNAL command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) with class 01 (warning) or you can create a table into which the trigger can insert its messages.